# program to convert decimal numbers to another base does not work correctly

Tags: java

I wrote this program to convert decimal numbers to another bases but when I run it with eclipse the answer is  `0` for any number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dtb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myscanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        int num= myscanner.nextInt();
        int base= myscanner.nextInt();  
        int i=0;
        int y=0;
        while (num >= base){
            int x = (num%base);
            num = num/base;

            y = (y + (x*(10^i)));   
        }
        System.out.println (y) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's kind of safe to think, most of the time, that eclipse works correctly

Comment: my program does not work correctly.

Comment: Your implementation part is wrong, just glancing by your tells that 'i' value is not getting changed, its remaining a constant i.e i=0 always and more over (10^i) wont give you the expected result in java ^ this is a bit wise XOR operator.

refer this link for the implementation part. 

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_logical_organization/number_system_conversion.htm

Answer (score 1):

The `^` operator doesn't do what you think. If you want to elevate to a power, use `Math.pow()`:

```
Math.pow(10, i)
```

but since this method returns a `double`, you will have to cast it to `int`:

```
(int) Math.pow(10, i)
```

Comment: In addition to that, the code in the question should increment the `i` variable inside the cycle and use the `num > 0` cycle condition instead of `num >= base`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your input. you num value should be greater than base value. eg: 30,20 output is 100.